# Evaluate limit of sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Evaluate limit of $x_n=(n+1)^k-n^k$ with $k\in (0,1)$.

I think that limit is 0 and I try using sandwich theorem, but I did not get the greater sequence.
Clearly, $0\leq x_n$.

Comment: Do you know the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Use Taylor's formula at order $1$  and equivalents:
$$(n+1)^k-n^k=n^k\Bigl[\Bigl(1+\frac 1n\Bigr)^k-1\Bigr]=n^k\biggl[1+\frac kn+o\Bigl(\frac 1n\Bigr)-1\biggr]\sim_\infty\frac k{n^{1-k}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

To flesh out @DanielFisher 's hint a little, let $f(x)=x^k$. Then, by the Mean Value 
Theorem, at each $n$ there is a $c_n$ between $n$ and $n+1$ such that 
$$f'(c_n) = \frac{(n+1)^k-n^k}{(n+1)-n} $$
Now the two things to keep in mind are that $0<k<1$, and that $n \rightarrow \infty \implies c_n \rightarrow \infty$. See if you can fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

If the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigl((x+1)^k-x^k\bigr)
=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{(1+t)^k-1}{t^k}
$$
exists, then it is the same as the limit of the sequence. You can apply l'Hôpital:
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{k(1+t)^{k-1}}{kt^{k-1}}
=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t^{1-k}}{(1+t)^{1-k}}=0
$$